# I always get a Invalid hook call and I don´t know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jsx

[image: Error]

My package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.21",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
    "@widgetbot/react-embed": "^1.4.0",
    "@windmill/react-ui": "^0.6.0",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "fastest-levenshtein": "^1.0.12",
    "framer-motion": "^3.10.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-focus-lock": "^2.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.7"
  },
}
```

I think it is no mismatching of versions or more than one copy of React.
I experimented 2 day around and I still haven´t got a solution.

Comment: Can you share how you are using a React hook? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese is the problem not the reactDOM.render function?

Comment: Dunno, can't see the entire code, but I suspect not since there's no hook being called there, it's likely just the code catching the error since it's the last stop in React on the way out to vanilla javascript land. I noticed also you don't have `react` as a dependency in your package.json file. What version of React are you using?

Comment: @DrewReese does that mean that I have to scann my entire code for a invalid hook call or are there any hints?

Comment: Expand the "10 stack frames were collapsed", it should show you where the issue started I would think.

Comment: a photo: https://ibb.co/sRYKGvb

Comment: Looks like an `useMemo` hook called in the `ApolloProvider` component. Perhaps you are mixing React versions.

Comment: this my react ls https://ibb.co/Ld8hRFm

Comment: if there is a problem pls write a solution as a answer so I can give you the reputation ❤

Comment: Based on your package.json file I think you're just missing the `react` dependency. I was curious if there was a reason why it wasn't there, but nothing in the Apollo client mentions it replacing React. You start by creating a React app via `create-react-app` and all their sandbox examples have `react` as a dependency.